# Turning on the flashlight does not keep the brightness

Tags: screen-brightness

I wrote a command to turn on the flashlight

```
echo 255 > sys/class/leds/flashlight/brightness
```

The flashlight turns on but after a second it shines darker. Why?

Comment: Did you mean `echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/flashlight/brightness`?

Comment: @iBug, oh, yes.. Sorry, command wrote correctly, but in question  not valid. I edit it

Comment: As @iBug pointed out the leading slash before sys?

Comment: @beeshyams Impossible to be the cause, since the OP managed to turn the flashlight on without the leading slash.

Comment: @iBug, yeah, managed

Comment: What happens if you read `brightness` after the LED brightness decreases? If the reading is no longer 255, then the driver might have been coded so as to disable maximum brightness (probably to prevent overheating).